# Pandas merge with overwrite and union together

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

Dataframe A - newest

```
Key1 Key2
-------------
L1   Value1
L2   Value2
L3   Value3
```

Dataframe B - old

```
Key1 Key2
--------------
L1   ValueOld1
L2   ValueOld2
L3   ValueOld3
R1   ValueOld1
R2   ValueOld2
R3   ValueOld3
```

I would like to `merge(A,B)` both dataframes A and B in a way that

- If Key1 exists in `A` then use row from `A`,
- If Key1 doesn't exists in `A` then copy row from `B`,

This could be named  `union with overwriting newest values`. I would like that this `merge(A,B)` method to be robust and handle well below situations for diffrent B dataframes :

Dataframe A

```
Key1 Key2
-------------
L1   Value1
L2   Value2
L3   Value3
```

1. Situation 1

Dataframe B

```
Key1 Key2
--------------
L1   ValueOld1
L2   ValueOld2
L3   ValueOld3
R1   ValueOld1
R2   ValueOld2
R3   ValueOld3
```

Merge(A,B)

```
Key1 Key2
--------------
L1   Value1
L2   Value2
L3   Value3
R1   ValueOld1
R2   ValueOld2
R3   ValueOld3
```

2. Situation 2

Dataframe B

```
Key1 Key2
--------------
L1   ValueOld1
L2   ValueOld2
R1   ValueOld1
```

Merge(A,B)

```
Key1 Key2
--------------
L1   Value1
L2   Value2
L3   Value3
R1   ValueOld1
```

3. Situation 3

Dataframe B

```
Key1 Key2
--------------
L1   ValueOld1
L2   ValueOld2
```

Merge(A,B)

```
Key1 Key2
--------------
L1   Value1
L2   Value2
L3   Value3
```

And last but not least, `Merge(A,B)` should preserve Key1 order in dataframe. How to achive this with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` then drop_duplicates:

```
pd.concat((new,old)).drop_duplicates('Key1')
```

Or with `isin` check which ids are not present in the old df and then concat:

```
pd.concat((new,old[~old['Key1'].isin(new['Key1'])]))
```

---

```
  Key1       Key2
0   L1     Value1
1   L2     Value2
2   L3     Value3
3   R1  ValueOld1
4   R2  ValueOld2
5   R3  ValueOld3
```

Comment: I have choosen `pd.concat((new,old)).drop_duplicates('Key1')` because it's simplest!

Comment: @s.paszko sometimes the 2 dataframes might be huge , in that case I would recommend using the second one, otherwise yes the first is more readable